# setting referral url in python urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python, html

I am using `urllib.urlretrieve` in Python to download websites.  Though some websites seem to not want me to download them, unless they have a proper referrer from their own site.  Does anybody know of a way I can set a referrer in one of Python's libraries or a external one to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com/')
req.add_header('Referer', 'http://www.python.org/')
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

adopted from http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 3):

`urllib` makes it hard to send arbitrary headers with the request; you could use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), which lets you build and send a [Request](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) object with arbitrary headers (including of course the -- alas sadly spelled;-) -- `Referer`).  Doesn't offer `urlretrieve`, but it's easy to just `urlopen` as you with and copy the resulting file-like object to disk if you want (directly, or e.g. via [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html?highlight=shutil#module-shutil) functions).

Answer (score 3):

Also, using `urllib2` with `build_opener` you can do this:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('Referer', 'http://www.python.org/')]
opener.open('http://www.example.com/')
```